# Code Style Testing for Chef using Jenkins and GitHub organizations

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, chef-infra, static-analysis

Currently, we commit Chef cookbooks to individual repos within our GitHub organization.  We are configuring a Jenkins job per repo / cookbook which will execute cookstyle first when a commit occurs, and if cookstyle passes with no issues, it will execute Test Kitchen. We have a template Jenkins job we copy and configure for each cookbook we create.

Does anyone know if it's possible to have GitHub hooks in Jenkins to listen for commit events across the entire organization, and then execute cookstyle on a repo where a commit occurred that contain a Chef cookbook?  I'd like to have one central job handling the lint testing for our organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't generally use a single job for this. You would use the GitHub Organization support to scan for all repositories and build them when they change. You can use webhooks to ping individual repos.

Comment: This would mean I'd have to maintain Jenkinsfiles for each cookbook, right? If my pipeline changes, I'd have to modify the Jenkinsfiles for a bunch of cookbooks. Is there an easier way to manage this or is it the only option? I was trying to manage the cookstyle job in one location instead of multiple locations.

Comment: Look up global pipeline libraries.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create github web hooks for your  github organization and configure your jenkins with the help of github plugin. Refer [this documentation](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224543927-GitHub-webhook-configuration) to see how to configure